# How to find text in an li and replace the li

Tags: jquery

I need to find a text in an `li` and then replace the whole `li` with another `li`.

In the below I want to find the second `li` and replace it with another 2 new `li`, so it looks like the second list below.

I have this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/hem.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">First</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/omoss.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Second</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/biljetter.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Third</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

So it looks like this.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/hem.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">First</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/omoss.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Second</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/omoss.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">This is the new one</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/biljetter.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Third</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

So basically I find the second one and replace it with the second one + another `li`. So replace it with this.

```
<li>
    <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/omoss.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
        <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title">Second</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/omoss.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
        <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title">This is the new one</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Any input really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you are just trying to append a new li element to an existing ul after the matching one? Is this what you want?

Comment: Sounds like you want to *insert* a new `li` after the found one.

Comment: Yes I need to insert a new li after the one with the text "Second".

Answer (score 1):

Your question says that you want to add a new li after second.

Use `eq()` with `append()` to achieve that.

```
$('ul > li:eq(1)').append("New li");
```

To replace, use `.html()`

```
$('ul > li:eq(1)').html("2nd li + New li");
```

To Change `a href` under 2nd li

```
$('ul > li:eq(1)').find('a').attr('href', 'http://google.com');
```

To Check the text, use `:contains()`

```
$('ul > li:contains("Second")').find('a').attr('href', 'http://google.com');
```

```js
$('ul > li:eq(1)').append("New li");

//$('ul > li:eq(1)').html("2nd li + New li");

//$('ul > li:eq(1)').find('a').attr('href', 'http://google.com');

//$('ul > li:contains("Second")').find('a').attr('href', 'http://google.com');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/hem.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title">First</div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/omoss.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title">Second</div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/biljetter.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title">Third</div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I need to run the code when I load the page and therefore I can't use eq(1) since that will look for it in all subpages as well, so I need to look for the text "Second" since that is only in my start menu, not i any li:s on subpages.

Comment: use contains  as `$('ul > li:contains('Second')')`

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson : I've updated my answer with `:contains`

Comment: Did you check ? is everything ok ?

Comment: Im about to test now.

Comment: Im trying with this to get the li: var secondLi = pageContainer.find('ul > li :contains("Second")'); But I get "The string did not match the expected pattern"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125326/discussion-between-loading-and-claes-gustavsson).

Comment: I have used the chat :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get second li element by using eq() selector. Then clone the second li element and insertAfter targeted second li:

```
 var $secondLi = $('li:eq(1)');
 var $secondLiClone = $secondLi.clone();
 $secondLiClone.find('.item-inner').text('This is the new one')
 $secondLi.after($secondLiClone);
```

```js
$(function(){
 var $secondLi = $('li:eq(1)');
 var $secondLiClone = $secondLi.clone();
 $secondLiClone.find('.item-inner').text('This is the new one')
 $secondLi.after($secondLiClone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/hem.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title">First</div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/omoss.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title">Second</div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://app.brollopsfeber.se/biljetter.asp" class="item-link item-content close-panel no-animation">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title">Third</div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to change the link as well, sorry did´t write that.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson: `$secondLiClone.find('.item-link').attr('href',newHref)`

Comment: Ok, I found a problem, I need to run this at startup and since I have several li:s on different pages this will run this on every page. So how can I instead look for the word "Second" and clone and replace that?

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson: by targeting unique parent container and then finding li in it.

Comment: Ok, then that is not an option. I don´t have a unique parent. How about if I run it only one time, then it will only affect my start menu and not li:s in subpages?